# Navigation bar logo doesn't appear on part of my project

Tags: image, components, laravel-blade, display, public

My landing page display logo in navbar:
[shows logo in nav bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4PRx.png)
However, for some reason, other pages doesn't show it:
[logo doesn't show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVGtx.png)

If I inspect picture, the landing page, which displays logo correctly, finds it at:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/Simply_Recipes_Logo.png
while other pages, where the logo doesn't display correctly, tries to reach it on:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/Simply_Recipes_Logo.png
and end with 404 not found.

I'm using the same layout.blade.php for both of these routes:

```
<html>

<head>
    @include('components.head')
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary mb-4">
        <div class="container">
            **<img src="Simply_Recipes_Logo.png" width="85" height="24">**
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="{{ url('public/recipes') }}" class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">All recipes</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-md-0 ">
                    @auth
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="{{ url('profile') }}" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">{{ auth()->user()->name }} profile</a>
                    </li> @endauth
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        @guest
                        <a href="{{ route('login') }}" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Login</a>
                        @endguest
                        @auth
                        <a href="{{ route('logout') }}" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Logout</a>
                        @endauth
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        @guest
                        <a href="{{ route('register') }}" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Signup</a>
                        @endguest
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        @yield('content')
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <footer class="py-3 my-4">
            <p class="text-center text-muted">&copy; 2023 Projektą sukūrė: Ieva S.</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

My routes:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMILk.png)

Any ideas how to solve it?

Tried to change routes, store logo in other folder.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it worked by changing the src of my pic, from:

```
<img src="Simply_Recipes_Logo.png" width="85" height="24">
```

to:

```
<img src="{{ asset('Simply_Recipes_Logo.png') }}" width="85" height="24">
```